# Can reach DNS but cannot resolve hostnames

Tags: dns

I have a problem with home network connection. I have been unable to diagnose it on my own.

Current setup is Huawei B525 router with LTE modem with SIM card and internet is shared in home thorugh WiFi.

Very often (usually in evenings) my internet stops working. Pings to IP addresses works, to hostnames don't.

Below code snippet with name resolution, which takes 5 seconds, and ping to DNS server which works fine.

```
wrobel@wrobel-ThinkPad:~$ time nslookup wp.pl 8.8.4.4
Server: 8.8.4.4
Address: 8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: wp.pl
Address: 212.77.98.9

real 0m5,069s
user 0m0,005s
sys 0m0,012s

wrobel@wrobel-ThinkPad:~$ ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=22.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=25.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=27.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=21.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=51 time=24.0 ms
^C
--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.789/23.470/27.879/2.644 ms
```

It happens usually in evening (so is somehow connected with network load). I've change DNS server (locally on PC and in DHCP server) but the problem still sometimes occurs.

Why I can reach DNS but cannot resolve hostnames ?

Comment: *Why I can reach DNS but cannot resolve hostnames ?* These processes use 2 different protocols, so your experiment tells about nothing (except the host is alive). Recommendation - find 10-20 different free DNS servers, the best way from different countries - look traces, the more vary is better (and check that they all may resolve), when the problem occurs then try to resolve using each. The result will show what step must be the nets. Anycase try TCP and UDP ping and trace by dest. port 53.

Comment: There may be an issue with traffic on the ISP network causing issues at a router or other device.  Try a trace route to a known IP off your ISP's network.  That may reveal the bottleneck.  I experienced a similar issue and it was a router three hops upstream